# How do I clear the SLOWLOG in redis?

Tags: redis

How do I clear the redis `SLOWLOG`?

```
# Server
redis_version:3.0.6
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:f62ea9ec3712ae8d
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.4.7
process_id:1489
run_id:05da042dddac2ef593eb8f2954ff7a93185797f7
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:7939847
uptime_in_days:91
hz:10
lru_clock:6602452
config_file:/etc/redis.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks `SLOWLOG RESET` was what I wanted.

https://redis.io/commands/slowlog#resetting-the-slow-log